# mouse out function is not working while we leave the mouse very slowly

Tags: jquery, css

normal mouse leave the function is working perfectly ,but if we are leaving the mouse very slowly then then mouse out function is not working ..

```
var timeoutId;
$('.box').mouseover(function(){
        var $this=$(this);
        if (!timeoutId) {
            timeoutId = window.setTimeout(function() {
            timeoutId = null;
                $this.animate({
                    marginTop:'-224px',
                    height:'300px'
                    })
    $this.find('.rotate-arrow').addClass('rotate');
    $this.find('.header-content-span').css('display','none');
                                                   },1000); }
            });
$('.box').mouseleave(function(){
        var $this=$(this);
         if (timeoutId) {
            window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
            timeoutId = null;
            $this.animate({
                marginTop:'0px',
                height:'77px'
                })
    $this.find('.rotate-arrow').removeClass('rotate');
    $this.find('.header-content-span').css('display','block');

        }
```

Comment: Can you post a link to your working page or a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way the code is set up, the `mouseleave` animation will not occur if you happen to stay hovered on the `.box` container for more than one second.

This is because the `timeoutId` is getting cleared as soon as `setTimeout` is triggered and the `mouseleave` callback contains logic to only execute the animation if the `timeoutId` is defined.

To resolve this, just pull the animation out of the if statement. Here is a simplified example:

```
var timeoutId;
$('.box').mouseenter(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!timeoutId) {
        timeoutId = window.setTimeout(function () {
            timeoutId = null;
            $this.stop().animate({
                height: '100px'
            });
        }, 1000);
    }
});
$('.box').mouseleave(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (timeoutId) {
        window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        timeoutId = null;
    }
    $this.stop().animate({
        height: '50px'
    });
});
```

**NOTE:** I used [`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) because it is the opposite event type to [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/). Depending on your specific situation, these two handlers tend to be better choices than using `mouseover` and `mouseout` due to the way they handle event bubbling for descendants of the bound objects.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PUC4E/)